# Conditional Formatting and Spreadsheet Control?

Tags: formatting, controls, conditional-statements, spreadsheet

I have a sheet with some conditional formatting which is going to be running in the background of a user form... On the user form I have a spreadsheet control which I need to populate with values from the worksheet.

I there a way I can do so and as well as keep the conditional formatting?
I really need that formatting on the spreadsheet control...

If there's a way to do conditional formatting on the spreadsheet control itself that would be great as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok so I came up with this code in the form initialize sub 

If Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A8").Value = "1" Then
Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A8").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
ElseIf Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A8").Value = "0" Then
Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A8").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If

It works for the first cell, but I have no Idea how to make this work for the entire row..

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way to fix my problem

```
For Each c In Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A8:XFD8")
If c.Value = "1" Then
c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
c.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
ElseIf c.Value = "0" Then
c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
c.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next c
```

basically I'm telling the form at initialize to check row number 10 for the cells with the value of "1" and replace the interior color and font color to blue and then do the same thing for the value "0" only replacing their color with red
And that's how you conditionally format a spreadsheet control :)

Hope this helps someone.